# pgfplots fillbetween layering issue

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

I am using `ticklabel style={fill=white}` with `pgfplots` to ensure my tick labels are readable despite my grid-lines.  However, it seems that when I use `fillbetween` the `ticklabel`s get drawn after the fill and therefore show up on top of my diagram.  If I use a `\draw` command to draw a rectangle, the rectangle ends up on top of the `ticklabel`, which is what I want.

Below is the code I am using and a figure

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-2,xmax=2,
        ymin=-1,ymax=2,
        x=1cm,y=1cm,
        axis lines=middle,
        grid=both,
        minor tick num=0,
        enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
        ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    ]

        \addplot[name path=f,no marks,mypink,thick,domain=-2:2, samples=25, draw=none] ({x},{x*x});
        \addplot[no marks,thick,domain=-2:2, samples=25,smooth] ({x},{x*x});
        \addplot[name path=g, no marks,thick,domain=-5:5, samples=2] ({x},{1.5});
        \addplot [thick, color=blue, fill=blue, fill opacity=0.5] fill between [of=f and g, split];

        \draw[fill=blue,opacity=0.5] (-1.5,-.5) rectangle(-.5,.5);

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `fill between` stuff is drawn on the layer `pre main` by default and all the rest on the layer `main`. To get your desired result just use the predefined layers `standard`.

(Please note that I also allowed myself to "optimize" your `\addplot` commands a bit. For more details have a look at the comments in the code.)

I also included the additional requirement of just filling the "closed" area as written in the comments below this answer.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            set layers=standard,    % <-- added
            xmin=-2,xmax=2,
            ymin=-1,ymax=2,
            x=1cm,y=1cm,
            axis lines=middle,
            grid=both,
            minor tick num=0,
            enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
            ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
            no markers,             % <-- moved common `\addplot' options here
            smooth,                 % <-- added, because it looks a bit "smoother"
        ]

            % combined first two `\addplot's to this one
            % and you don't need a parametric plot here
            \addplot [name path=f,draw=black,thick,domain=-2:2, samples=25] {x^2};
            \addplot [name path=g,thick,domain=-5:5, samples=2] {1.5};

            \addplot [fill=none] fill between [
                    of=f and g,
                    split,
                    % draw only selected ones:
                    % every segment no 0/.style: invisible
                    every segment no 1/.style={
                        fill=blue,opacity=0.5
                    },
                    % every segment no 2/.style: invisible
                ];

            \draw[fill=blue,opacity=0.5] (-1.5,-.5) rectangle(-.5,.5);

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Exactly what I needed!  In my original, I was only shading the bounded region which is why I had two different plots (one had a restricted domain).  Is there a way to shade only the bounded region but still have only one curve for each?

Comment: Do you mean with "bounded area" only the "closed curve" between the x values -1.22 and 1.22? But then I don't know what you mean with "only one curve for each".

Comment: I wanted to shade the region whose x coords were between -1.22 and 1.22.  I still wanted to draw the whole curve, so I used an invisible plot with domain -1.22 to 1.22 for the fillbetween and a visible plot with full domain to draw the curve.

Comment: Of course you can do that. Have a look at my edited answer.