# PGFPlots fillbetween layer issue with main layer

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

I am using `fill between` to create some diagrams where I need semi-transparent fillings above ploted lines. As normally fillings are put into a separate layer `pre main` below plot lines, I tried to move the fillings via `on layer=main`. They disappear? I don't know if this behaviour is intended. I can draw them on any other layer but this one. See the minimal example below:

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot+[name path=A,domain=0:1,samples=10] {x};
            \addplot+[name path=B,domain=0:1, samples=10] {x^2};
            \addplot fill between[of=A and B, on layer=main];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}       
\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image: Change <code>on layer=main</code> and you can see the filling]

My workaround at the moment is to draw everything onto the `pre main` layer.

#### Edit:

Giving the option in the `\addplot` part of the statement has absolutely no effect:

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:1]
        \addplot+[name path=A, draw=none, mark=none] {x};
        \addplot+[name path=B, draw=none, mark=none] {x^2};
        \addplot+[draw=black, mark=none] {x-0.1};
        \addplot [on layer=axis foreground, fill=green] fill between[of=A and B];
        \addplot+[draw=blue, mark=none] {x-0.15};                       
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image: No effect]

Comment: Why do you desire/need to write the fillings in the `main` layer? The `pgfplots` documentation explicitly says that the `fillbetween` fillings are drawn in the `pre main` layer on purpose, to avoid possible overlappings with other plots

Comment: Easily said I need to create a line with a thin area along/surrounding it (like an error interval). The area has the same color as the line but is somewhat transparent - the for a unity. Now this line with its shadow crosses a second, similar line. This looks weird as the mix of the lines is not expected.

Basically I just expect `pgf fill between` to plot something onto a layer I specify as it normally does and not just hide it in case I specify a magic layer. If there is a deeper meaning to it I can accept that but I don't understand the inconsistency.

Comment: Can [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343721/pgfplots-fillbetween-layering-issue?rq=1) be relevant, perhaps?

Comment: I worked through that thread before but thank you for providing the link (:
Actually it explains why I have the `on layer=main` in my code (so far it's documented behaviour exactly as the manual v1.13 by Christian Feuersänger explains). What neither explain is why fillings moved to `main` disappear.

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately I don't have the answer, then…

Comment: No problem, I appreciate that you looked into my problem!

Comment: Good luck, then

Comment: you need to give the option to the addplot part `\addplot[on layer=main, fill=green] fill between[of=A and B ];`

Comment: Thank you for your comment percusse! I tried that before, it has absolutely no effect there. See the additional example I added to my question above. Whereas putting it where I had it before it changed the layer it was drawn on indeed (e.g. `axis foreground` works) except that it is impossible to "unhide" it on the `main` layer.

Comment: P.S.: Reported as ticket #164 to the developers: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/164/